# Overset over an array

Tags: overset, overbrace

I'm trying to get `overbrace` and `overset` effect on the left but with this code I'm getting the result on the right.

```
$f_V(v) = \left\{ \begin{array}{cc}
     \frac{dF_Z(z)}{dx} = \overset{symbol2}{\overset{symbol1}{\overbrace{2\pi(\frac{\alpha q}{4^\pi})^{\nicefrac{7}{8}}}}} \\
     0\\        
    \end{array} \right.$
```

Any idea how to place symbol 1 and symbol 2 over the array? Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, I use display style math, delimited with `\[...\]` rather than `$...$`.  I used `\dfrac` where needed to get embedded fraction in display style.  Importantly, I `\smash`ed the `\overset` fraction, so as not to adversely affect the left brace.  However, this comes with a need to manually compensate for the resultant lack of vertical space above, which I did with a `\bigskip` before entering math mode.  Also added, for the same reason, was extra space manually between the two lines of the equation with `\\[10pt]`.

I also opted to make the parens `\Big`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicefrac,amsmath,lipsum}
\DeclareMathOperator\dla{dla}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]\bigskip
\[f_V(v) = \left\{ \begin{array}{cl}
     \dfrac{dF_Z(z)}{dx} = \smash{\overset{I>E}{\overset{\cdot \mathrm{II}}{%
       \overbrace{2\pi\Bigl(\dfrac{\alpha q}{4^\pi}\Bigr)^{\nicefrac{7}{8}}}}}}%
       \ldots& \dla z \le 0 \\[10pt]
     0 & \dla z > 0\\        
    \end{array} \right.
    \]
    \lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

[image]

If I misunderstood the bottom overset, perhaps it was intended to be `\overset{\rotatebox{90}{$\overset{.}{=}$}}`, requiring the `graphicx` package.  Furthermore, if that underset requires right-alignment, as indicated in the OP's MWE, then `stackengine` can help:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicefrac,amsmath,lipsum,graphicx,stackengine}
\stackMath
\DeclareMathOperator\dla{dla}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]\bigskip
\[f_V(v) = \left\{ \begin{array}{cl}
     \dfrac{dF_Z(z)}{dx} = \smash{\overset{I>\stackunder{\scriptstyle E}{%
       \rotatebox{90}{$\scriptstyle\overset{.}{=}$}}}{%
       \overbrace{2\pi\Bigl(\dfrac{\alpha q}{4^\pi}\Bigr)^{\nicefrac{7}{8}}}}}%
       \ldots& \dla z \le 0 \\[10pt]
     0 & \dla z > 0\\        
    \end{array} \right.
    \]
    \lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Second solution worked perfectly, thank you very much :)